# How can I produce a call chain of Android application layer function call to linux kernel system calls?

Tags: android, kernel, system-calls, android-debug

I have been trying to get behind the call chain of some of the android framework's app initiated termination functions such as `System.exit(0)`, `finish()`, `finishAndRemoveTask()`, etc. I have used **strace** to find system level traces, for `System.exit()` function of android application layer, I believe the kernel system level signal is `SigKill`, as this claim is supported by the following `strace` log.

[image]

I wanted to get behind the system-level calls or signals behind other android application layer functions such as `finish()`.

I have tried to use Android Studio's built-in debugger, however, that only gives me all the call chains in java API level. I wanted to debug and get the full call chain from java function to native C/C++ library calls to kernel system level calls. That is `function X()` in java calls `function Y()` in native C/C++ libraries and that calls system level `function Z()`. I need the call chain flow from `X -> Y -> Z`.

How can I achieve that? I have also tried `simpleperf` but that does not provide the complete call-graph from application layer to system level calls.